# Error trying to publish config file of laravel-livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Reading laravel-livewire docs at
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation

I tried to publish The Config File and I got unexpected results

```
$ php artisan livewire:publish

                                              
  Command "livewire:publish" is not defined.  
                                              
  Did you mean one of these?                  
      livewire:configure-s3-upload-cleanup    
      livewire:copy                           
      livewire:delete                         
      livewire:discover                       
      livewire:make                           
      livewire:move                           
      livewire:stubs                          
      stub:publish                            
      sweetalert:publish                      
      vendor:publish
```

Why so and which command have I use to to publish config file ?

I have :

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^1.3",
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have installed `"livewire/livewire": "^1.3" ` so `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:config`

Comment: Here are the correct docs: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/1.x/installation#publishing-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed

```
"livewire/livewire": "^1.3",
```

and are referring to version 2 documentation
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation

Use liverwire version 2 or [version 1 documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/1.x/installation#publishing-config) instead.

In case others wonder, the line `"livewire/livewire": "^1.3"` can be found in `require` section of the `composer.json` file in the project's root directory.

Comment: For Laravel Livewire 2 use: "livewire/livewire": "^2.0"